# Could I use an hashing function for Symmetric encryption?

Tags: encryption, hash

I know there are way better and more tested encryption methods, but I was wondering if the following code could be use for symmetric encryption?

```
var text = "hello";
var password = "mypass";
var message = hash(text) + encrypt(text, password);

function encrypt(text, password){
    var key = hash(hash(text) XOR hash(password));
    var passphrase = key;
    while(passphrase.length < text.length){
        key = hash(key);
        passphrase += key;
    }
    passphrase = passphrase.substring(0, text.length);
    return text XOR passphrase;
}
```

It can easily be decrypted if you know the password.

Is there any flaw to this simple algorithm?

N.B.: A similar question was asked [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10507/using-whirlpool-hashing-function-to-encrypt-data) but the algorithm doesn't work...

Comment: See the question I linked as duplicate, and the [accepted answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/96/13625). Your construction seems weak for a similar reason. The answer also links to a more secure idea.

Comment: @otus I'm not sure we have to close this question though as it describes a different algorithm than the question you pointed to. We can hack this particular one apart in our answers here. How useful that is remains questionable, I admit.

Comment: @owlstead, did you look at them? They only differ in how they calculate the initial block of keystream from the key. Either way, doesn't really matter to me.

Comment: @otus The answer you linked was very useful but isn't his first block really insecured as the attacker know H(plaintext) and the cipherpart_0 so he can get the H(key) very easily?

Comment: @Gudradain, yes, I didn't notice that. It's completely broken.

Comment: @otus To be fair, my initial scan did not identify the main issue either. But we're already up to 4 security related issues now.

Comment: @owlstead Well, that’s where [that non-accepted answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/150/12164) starts to shine for a short moment… by pointing to *Bear* and *Lion*. From my point of view, both questions ask the same as there’s not much difference between *“Could I use an hashing function for Symmetric encryption?”* and *“Is it feasible to build a stream cipher from a cryptographic hash function?”*. In both cases the answer is *yes*. **BUT:** I think this question would gain from changing the title into something like ***“Is this a correct way to use a hash for symmetric encryption?”***

Comment: @Gudradain One of the most obvious things is, that your algorithm does not provide any kind of *authentication* or *data integrity* checks. I’m unsure if that’s a problem or not, since you didn’t specify your exact security requirements… but since you’re using a hash here anyway, you might want to take a look at the obvious solution: add a [**HMAC**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac). (In fact, you could even base your whole encryption thing on HMACs.)

Comment: Sorry to say so, but I just stumbled upon [“Constructing a block-cipher from a hash function”](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5298/12164), which handles the other (non-streamcipher) side of “symmetric encryption”. Add that to [the question @otus already pointed to](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18127/could-i-use-an-hashing-function-for-symmetric-encryption#comment40155_18127), and this one ends up being nothing more than a questions asking for cryptanalysis of a cipher design, [which we “do not accept” according to our help center](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

The basic flaw is the same as indentified in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/96/13625) I linked in comments:

If you know the plaintext for block $i$, you can derive the key for that block and then derive the rest of the keystream from that key. Thus, an attacker can simply make guesses on the message until they find one that allows them to decrypt the rest of the message.

---

A better way to build a stream cipher from a hash function would be to hash a key and a counter and a unique nonce so two messages always get different keystreams and knowing a keystream block will not help in calculating the later blocks.

For example: $k_i = H(K||N||i)$

Better yet, use an existing stream cipher, or the stream cipher mode of a hash function that has one, like Skein (or IIRC SHA-3).

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your security requirements. Basically it is OK to create a (slow!) stream cipher using a secure hash method, given that the password has a large enough security margin.

But your code has at least the following issues:

- *you leak enough information in the first block to regenerate the key stream from a known plaintext* (thanks otus);
- you have to leak `hash(text)` to an attacker, otherwise you cannot decrypt;
- you can distinguish if the same text has been encrypted twice with the same password (the encryption is deterministic as it misses an IV);
- you don't deploy a password based key derivation funcation instead of a cryptographic hash over the password to generate the initial key.

The first one completely breaks your cipher. #2 and #3 are enough to consider the cipher broken, but may allow you to use a cipher (if it weren't for #1). #4 will make it easy for an attacker to brute-force your password, or perform a dictionary attack.

Not all hash algorithm implementations are protected against side channel attacks (less so than block ciphers anyway). And block ciphers are designed for this purpose and much faster. Stream ciphers such as Salsa20 will completely blow this implementation out of the water with regards to speed.

Comment: Why is it a problem to leak hash(text)? If the hash is secure the hash(text) is useless to reveal the plaintext.

Comment: Right. What if you have three plaintexts, "Yes", "Yes" and "No" and send them over a line? What if you send a credit card number for which only 4 digits are unknown?

Comment: Oh, so I was using the hash(text) as a sort of IV to protect my password, but what I really should have use is an IV (like a random number) instead of the hash(text). This answer made it clear http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42642/should-aes-always-give-the-same-output

Comment: Yup, that's it. You should also look at Password Based Key Derivation Functions instead of performing hash(password). As you may have noticed, you should only use your scheme for practicing crypto.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my take on your algorithm. I'll try to perform the known plaintext attack.

- Knowing the plaintext allows to recover the keystream (`passphrase`) by simply XORing it.
- This in turn reveals the value of `hash(hash(text) XOR hash(password))` -- simply the first hash block, and the value of `hash(text)` is known (by virtue of KPA plus it is leaked by your message construction).
- So the attack boils down to finding a preimage for the value `hash(hash(text) XOR hash(password))`. It may be computationally feasible to utilise rainbow tables for that as you do not use any kind of salt for this hash. I think there should be precomputed tables for this sort of attack as they are useful in unwinding the `hash(hash(hash(hash(...))))` construct as well.
- If finding the preimage is successful, the attacker would know `hash(text) XOR hash(password)` candidate(s), where recovering `hash(password)` is trivial. Which one is the correct one can be verified by encrypting the test data.
- At this point, the attacker would be able at least to forge arbitrary messages, as the plaintext of `password` is not required, only its hash.